# Css position in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a file uploading site and my template works fine in every browser except ie7

the google ads are not showing correctly in ie7, i tried applying css properties **display: block** and also tried with **inline**, specified **width** and **height**, specified **position: relative**, so what should i add to css to get it correctly positioned with floating element above it.

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/d2/ca/5f/1044221/0/1.png](http://img2.pict.com/d2/ca/5f/1044221/0/1.png)
*Image above is exactly what is accepted.*

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/36/7c/eb/1044222/0/2.png](http://img2.pict.com/36/7c/eb/1044222/0/2.png)
*Ad stays where it is even if the above element decreases in size*

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/5b/c7/94/1044230/0/3.png](http://img2.pict.com/5b/c7/94/1044230/0/3.png)
*Again Ad stays where it is even if the above element increases in size*

Thank You

Comment: Could you post some markup? It looks like you are using absolute positioning when it's not necessary.

Comment: nope the element is not positioned absolutely

Comment: <div id="1"><div id="2"><div id="Google_ad"></div>here is rest of the content</div></div>

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to give more info for this to be properly answered - a link to an example page would help.

Comment: Please provide the source HTML/CSS you're using or a link. It's going to be impossible to debug this otherwise.

Comment: I figured the link in the screenshots were worth following; http://mymegafiles.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be some absolute positioning going on on the iframe that google includes (`#google_ads_frame`). This is set to left: 0; and top: 0; though, so it shouldn't be displayed where you show us in the images. I don't have a machine with IE7 installed right now, so I wasn't able to check properly, but I did go through the ad code, and that is the only place I found `position: absolute`. Not having used Google Ads before, I really don't know what kind of configurations you have available to play with, but I hope you find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your doctype to fixed and it should sort it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
```